# iOS VoIP calls not working when app in terminated state

Tags: xcode, voip, ios13, callkit, pushkit

I'm able to receive the new call push notification and report the call,  but when the app is in terminated state I'm not receiving the notification and I get missed call only.

Below the code I use to handle the new call push notification:

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(PKPushType)type withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completion {

    NSString * nameA = [NSBundle.mainBundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]
    CXProviderConfiguration *config = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc]initWithLocalizedName:nameA];
    config.supportsVideo = FALSE;
    config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"callkit_logo"]);

    NSArray *ar = @[ [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)CXHandleTypeGeneric] ];
    NSSet *handleTypes = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:ar];
    [config setSupportedHandleTypes:handleTypes];
    [config setMaximumCallGroups:2];
    [config setMaximumCallsPerCallGroup:1];

    self.cxProvider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:config];

    NSDictionary *dict = [payload.dictionaryPayload objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString * callm = [dict objectForKey:@"callfrom"];
    if (callm.length == 0) {
        callm = @"CALL BB";
    }
    CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:callm];
    CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle;
    callUpdate.supportsDTMF = YES;
    callUpdate.supportsHolding = YES;
    callUpdate.supportsGrouping = NO;
    callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = NO;
    callUpdate.hasVideo = NO;

    self.uuid = [NSUUID UUID];

    [self.cxProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:self.uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error1 ----> %@",error);
        if (error) {
            if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
                [self.cxProvider reportCallWithUUID:self.uuid endedAtDate:[NSDate now] reason:CXCallEndedReasonFailed];
            } else {
            }
        }
    }];
    CXCallController *callController = [[CXCallController alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()]; 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        CXEndCallAction *endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:self.uuid];
        CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endCallAction];

        [callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error2 ----> %@",error);
            if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
                [self.cxProvider reportCallWithUUID:self.uuid endedAtDate:[NSDate now] reason:CXCallEndedReasonRemoteEnded];
            } else {
            }
        }];
    });

    [self processPush:payload.dictionaryPayload];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{completion();});
}
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? My first starting point would be: Did you make sure that you correctly set up push notifications? Is the `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` called at all?
It is also not quite clear to me where your request of the `CXEndCallAction` is placed in the code. This should definitely not be part of your `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload`.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to receiving notification..and reporting. When app in terminated state I get missed call only..not the call.. please help me

Comment: It's part of the didReceieveIncomingPushWithPayload all I posted code..

Comment: @PashaMohamed Did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be in the last line of your code. You're calling the completion block inside a `dispatch_async`, so it will execute in the next run-loop. The problem is that when the app is the terminated state, you probably do not have a next run-loop.

Try to call the completion block inside the completion block of the `reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID`:

```
[self.cxProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:self.uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error1 ----> %@",error);
        if (error) {
            if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
                [self.cxProvider reportCallWithUUID:self.uuid endedAtDate:[NSDate now] reason:CXCallEndedReasonFailed];
            } else {
            }
        }
        completion(); // <-----
}];
```

Comment: i modified code same as you told ..but still not getting same issue not getting calls..please help me

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, we established that `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` is called correctly, so push notifications have apparently been set up correctly.

One thing is off here and that may be the cause of you getting missed call notifications instead of the chance to let the call go through normally:
After reporting the incoming call with 
`[self.cxProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:self.uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError *error)`
you are directly reporting a call end to iOS with

```
CXEndCallAction *endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:self.uuid];
        CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endCallAction];

        [callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError *error)
```

That should not be the case: You are essentially reporting to iOS first that you have a new incoming call and then only milliseconds later, in the next main run loop, you are reporting that the remote party hung up. Such a flow would only make sense in scenarios where the remote party actually hangs up in the mean time, e.g. because the connection setup is too slow or the caller hung up very quickly again. But from what I understood, this is not (typically) the case here. So I think you would not want to report the call having ended to iOS shortly after handling the push notification. Maybe you can try if it works, if you remove the following lines:

```
CXCallController *callController = [[CXCallController alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()]; 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        CXEndCallAction *endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:self.uuid];
        CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endCallAction];

        [callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error2 ----> %@",error);
            if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
                [self.cxProvider reportCallWithUUID:self.uuid endedAtDate:[NSDate now] reason:CXCallEndedReasonRemoteEnded];
            } else {
            }
        }];

    });
```

Another thing I would investigate is: Is there an error message that give any clues in the original reporting in
`[self.cxProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:self.uuid update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError *error)`?

Finally, I would advise to verify that your completion handler actually gets called at the end, by setting a breakpoint or adding a logger in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    completion();
    NSLog(@"completion handler called");
});
```

Comment: no, im not getting any errors.. while doing like this...please help

Comment: @PashaMohamedI'm also facing the same issue as you. When I do make VOIP calls in my app and if my app is terminated at that time when i receive the call directly this delegate method ```perform action: CXEndCallAction``` is getting called. Please suggest any solution.